# Convert rows into columns using pivot in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i want to convert rows into columns using PIVOT function.

Example is below

Table

```
EMP No   EMP Name
-------  --------
1         ABC
2         PQR
```

Output should be

```
Col1         Col2
----         ----
Emp No         1
Emp Name       ABC
EMP No          2
Emp Name       PQR
```

I am ok with loop and all however we should have used PIVOT, have serached google however has not got anything matching.

Please suggest and send some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually for you requirement, you need `unpivot`, not `pivot`. But for that, datatype of both columns should be same, character in this case

```
with tab(emp_no, emp_name) as (
select '1' ,'abc' from dual union all
select '2' ,'PQR' from dual)
----
--End of Data Perparation
----
select * 
  from tab
unpivot (col2 for col1 in ( emp_no as 'EMP No', emp_name as 'Emp Name'));
```

Output

```
|     COL1 | COL2 |
|----------|------|
|   EMP No |    1 |
| Emp Name |  abc |
|   EMP No |    2 |
| Emp Name |  PQR |
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can be done using PIVOT. You can select the columns separately and UNION them.

```
select 'Emp No' col1, emp_no col2 from tab
union all
select 'Emp Name', emp_name from tab;
```

Note that, both the columns should be of same datatype. Else you need to cast/convert one of them.

Also, the result may not be in the order you want. You need to sepecify the order by clause explicitly.

```
select col1, col2 from(
    select 'Emp No' col1, emp_no col2, emp_no from tab
    union all
    select 'Emp Name', emp_name, emp_no from tab
    )
order by emp_no, case col1 when 'Emp No' then 1 else 2 end;
```

[sqlfidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/04bbc/12).